# Why don't Angular HTML Templates know about Augmented Object fields in WebStorm?

Tags: angular, webstorm

I am using an external JS library in Angular.

That library contains a class `TypeRef`.

I import the library and apply Module Augmentation:

```
declare module '@axinpm/atcl-api-lib' {
    interface TypeRef {
        label: string;
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(TypeRef.prototype, 'label', {
    get: function label() {
        let label = ... some logic
        return label;
    }
});
```

I now can use this new field `label`in TypeScript code:

[image]

But if I use it in an Angular HTML template, WebStorm does not recognize it:

[image]

The compiled Angular Application works fine.

Is this a bug in WebStorm?

Comment: just checked - it works fine for me in WebStorm 2019.1. I'd suggest creating a support ticket, providing a sample app that can be used to recreate the issue

Comment: thanks for the feedback. did you also augment an external library class or a internal/project class?

Comment: I did this with a project class